# ListPlot with different interval

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I met a complicated function y=f(x) in my research, this function has no analytical expression, and only numerical values are accessible to me (So I can only use ListPlot rather than Plot). I need to plot it with points evenly distributed in my graph, and I don't know how to do it. Let me just simplify my problem as follows:

Now I am trying to plot `y=1/x` around x=0:

```
ListPlot[Table[{n,y = 1/n}, {n, -10, 10}]]
```

and I can get:

[image]

I am happy with those data with `|n|>3`, but I am not happy with the data around `n=0`, so I want to find a way to plot more data around `n=0` while keep the data density elsewhere unchanged. I know I can plot two graphs with different range and interval of n and use `Show[]` to combine them together, but I hope to find a neat way to it. Thank you!

Comment: Just to make sure, you don't want to use `Plot`, right?

Comment: Does `Plot[1/x, {x, -10, 10}, Mesh -> 30, MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, MeshStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, PlotStyle -> None]` work for you?

Comment: Plot can be used on numeric functions: `func[n_?NumericQ] := 1/n;
Plot[func@n, {n, -1, 1}]`

Answer (score 3):

*So after the other answer and comment I really really hope you ment working with ListPlot. Otherwise im sad :D*

-

So it's not an anwser with a pretty short code but it works well.

To uniformly distribute your points, we want the length between adjacent points to be constant. So we formulate:

$$l=\sqrt{(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2}$$
$$l=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(1/x_1-1/x_2)^2}$$

Solving this for $x_2$ gives two solutions. One backward (the first) and one forward solution (represented by [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html)).
So if we define a $l$ and a $y_{min,max}$-value

```
l = 1/5; (*length between points*)
yBorder = 2; (*max absolute y value*)
sol = x2 /. Solve[l == Sqrt[(x1 - x2)^2 + (1/x1 - 1/x2)^2], x2, Reals];
```

we could solve the points as long as they are in the range using [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) and [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) in a [`Do`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html) from both sides starting by $x=3$ and $x=-3$:

```
xPoints = Reap[
    Do[
     x = 3*(-1)^(i + 1); Sow[x];
     y = 1/x;
     While[Abs[y] <= yBorder, x = N[sol[[i]] /. {x1 -> x}]; Sow[x]; 
      y = 1/x];
     , {i, 1, 2}]
    ][[2, 1]];
```

getting everything together and ploting it:

```
l = 1/5; (*length between points*)
yBorder = 2; (*max absolute y value*)
xBorder = 3;
sol = x2 /. Solve[l == Sqrt[(x1 - x2)^2 + (1/x1 - 1/x2)^2], x2, Reals];
xPoints = Reap[
    Do[
     x = xBorder*(-1)^(i + 1); Sow[x];
     y = 1/x;
     While[Abs[y] <= yBorder, x = N[sol[[i]] /. {x1 -> x}]; Sow[x]; 
      y = 1/x];
     , {i, 1, 2}]
    ][[2, 1]];
yPoints = 1/xPoints;
points = Transpose[{xPoints, yPoints}];
ListPlot[points]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

**Attention:**
You should also take the [`AspectRatio`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AspectRatio.html) and [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) into account, since it seems that for bigger $y$-values the distance between the adjacent points shrinks or grows which is not the case.

I've did it for you (which was more easier than i thought):

It uses the fact that we just need to *stretch* one of the coordinates to the PlotRange and AspectRatio:

$$l=\sqrt{(\Phi\cdot (y_{max}-y_{min})/(x_{max}-x_{min})\cdot\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2}$$

Where $\Phi$ is the inverse AspectRatio which is by default the [`GoldenRatio`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GoldenRatio.html).

```
l = 1; (*length between points*)
yBorder = 10; (*max absolute y value*)
xBorder = 50;
sol = x2 /. 
   Solve[l == 
     Sqrt[(yBorder/xBorder)^2*
        GoldenRatio^2*(x1 - x2)^2 + (1/x1 - 1/x2)^2], x2, Reals];
xPoints = Reap[
    Do[
     x = xBorder*(-1)^(i + 1); Sow[x];
     y = 1/x;
     While[Abs[y] <= yBorder, x = N[sol[[i]] /. {x1 -> x}]; Sow[x]; 
      y = 1/x];
     , {i, 1, 2}]
    ][[2, 1]];
yPoints = 1/xPoints;
points = Transpose[{xPoints, yPoints}];
ListPlot[points, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I can only use ListPlot since the real problem I met is so complicated that no analytical answer can be used for Plot. It is not neat, but I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use `Plot` then...

You can do it fairly easily with `Piecewise`

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{1/x, -10 <= x < 0}, {1/x, 0 < x <= 10}}]
Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: `Plot[1/x, {x, -10, 10}]` will give this `Plot`

Comment: @BobHanlon You are right but the idea was split the interval.